# Rails: Template is missing when AJAX and .js.rjs files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

I am trying to execute an AJAX routine with rails
the code runs normally but the response doesnt..

I get this error

Template is missing

```
Missing template line_items/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "D:/ruby/depot/app/views"
```

I created the create.js.rjs inside line_items directory like the book Agile Web Development says it is to be, but the error insists..

```
#file line_items_controller.rb

def create
    @cart = current_cart
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = add_product(@cart, product.id)

    respond_to do |format|
       if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to store_url }
        format.js 
        format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
        #...
      end
    end
  end
```

and inside my create.js.rjs I got this

```
page.replace_html('cart', render(@cart))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rjs is not a valid format anymore I guess. Use js.erb instead. Also manual you're following is outdated since none uses prototype anymore.

Comment: I've been noticing.. thats rails oficial site faults.. they still recommends this book that I say in the question.. see that http://rubyonrails.org/documentation